# Conectar sql server windows authentication

Tags: java, sql-server

Tengo una instacia de sql server, que se puede conectar tanto por windows authentication como por sql auhthentication:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Connection conn = null;
     String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
     String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databasename=Test;";
     String userName = "sa"; 
     String password = "paquito";
     Statement stmt;
     try{
       Class.forName(driver);//.newInstance();
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
       stmt = conn.createStatement();
       System.out.println("conectado = "); 
       conn.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Esa conexión funciona sin problemas, vamos a la de windows authentication:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Connection conn = null;
     String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
     String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databasename=Test;integratedSecurity=true";
     String userName = "paco"; 
     String password = "";
     Statement stmt;
     try{
       Class.forName(driver);//.newInstance();
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
       stmt = conn.createStatement();
       System.out.println("conectado = "); 
       conn.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

y me sale el sgte error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: No se puede abrir la base de datos "Test" solicitada por el inicio de sesión. Error de inicio de sesión. ClientConnectionId:577da72f-f0d4-4ac6-abab-243f0f84d0e3
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:279)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:99)
```

NOTA: desde el sql management puedo conectarme de las 2 formas.

Comment: Tienes el fichero sqljdbc_auth.dll en el directorio bin de tomcat?

Comment: uso eclipse y lo despliego con el mismo servidor de aplicacioens q viene con defecto que no es tomcat, ese fichero lo tengo en windows/system32

Comment: bueno es una aplicacion java, por lo que hago run->java application